# Cons operator (:) adding list to empty list - [x]:foo xs

Tags: haskell

The cons operator is used to add elements to a list so `1:2:[]` would equal `[1,2]` however why does the following code work then;

```
foo :: [a] -> [[a]]
foo [] = []
foo (x:xs) = [x]:foo xs
```

Here we are adding `[x]` to foo xs which will evaluate to `[]` so essentially in the end it would be `[x]:[]` which is allowed in Haskell. But [x]:[1,2,3] isn't allowed why is this?

Comment: Doesn't mention adding lists using cons so [x] : []

Comment: The type of `:` is `a -> [a] -> [a]`. So you cannot pass a list in front of it. Something like this will work `x:[]`. If you really want to add two lists, then `++` is the operator you are looking for.

Comment: Compile the code I have supplied it compiles perfectly however I am confused why [x]:foo xs works?

Comment: Its just a list of lists isn't it? It even says so in the type declaration. So what happens is if you in put [1, 2, 3] into foo you get [1] : [2] : [3] : [] which is perfectly fine. Imagine [a] being the element and "[[a]]" being your list.

Comment: So why cant you do [1] : [1,2,3]

Comment: because [1] is different from 1. [[1], 1, 2, 3] or does that look like the elements of the list have the same type? what your trying to do is list concatenation with (++)

Comment: Great thanks I wanted to understand : operator?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure maybe you should read through this. Combined with the knowledge that haskell is strongly and statically typed it explains a lot.